# useDelimiter Scanner for repeated data

Tags: java

I have a problem in reading the data from a text file. I am using useDelimiter to store a part of the string into a map. The pattern I use will be repeated later in the file and the scanner will not read further.

example text,

a:1, (values), b:2, (values), c:3, (values), d:4, (values), e:5, (values), a:1, (values), b:2, (values)...........

```
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("a:1,");
(mapping code)
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(sc1.next()).useDelimiter("b:2,");
(mapping code)
     Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(sc2.next()).useDelimiter("c:3,");
(mapping code).......

Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(sc2.next()).useDelimiter("a:1,");
```

The data is not read after using the same pattern. Tried to use regex to read string once. didn't work.

Comment: can you explain more? do you create a map from a to 1? then what is values?

Comment: @Amin I create a hash map for values. I am trying to group all the values to parse it. but unable to read the data after second a:1

Comment: do you mean you put all (values) for a:1 in a map from a to them. then what is 1 and 2 for `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 1):

Set the delimiter to the regex you need. Scanner doesn't give direct access to the delimiter match, but you can substring to get it. Then just use the key/values as necessary for your map.

```
    String text = "a:1, (values:a1), b:2, (values:b2), c:3, (values:c3), a:1, (values:a1), b:2, (values:b2)";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text).useDelimiter("[a-z]:[0-9]+, ");

    int previous = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String value = scanner.next();

        MatchResult match = scanner.match();
        String key = text.substring(previous, match.start());
        previous = match.end();

        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Outputs:

```
a:1, 
(values:a1), 
b:2, 
(values:b2), 
c:3, 
(values:c3)
a:1, 
(values:a1), 
b:2, 
(values:b2)
```

Comment: Is there a way to include the pattern in the delimiter in the scanner object so it's not removed?

Comment: As far as I can tell, anything in the delimiter gets thrown away. You could use Pattern/Matcher to include both, but I think your regex will start to get more complicated (probably requiring some lookahead). You could also try with StringTokenizer, which has a returnDelims option, but that seems more clunky IMHO.

Comment: For the code you send what if it is like  String text = "a:1, (values:a1), b:2, (values:b2), c:3, (values:c3), a:1, (values:a1), b:2, (values:b2), and so on"; the data after second a:1 wont be matched or read id usedelimiter is used

Comment: Not 100% sure I follow, but repeated keys (e.g. a:1) are just fine. Updated "text" and output to reflect this.